# How to integrate a cookie banner (GDPR) in Keyclaok?

Tags: keycloak, gdprconsentform

I want to integrate a cookie banner (permit/deny/...) in the login screen of Keycloak.
The Keycloak login screen is the first page a user gets to see and Keycloak already wants to set cookies.

Therefore I need to include a JS like `<script id="..." src="https://the-service-provider/the-script.js" data-cbid="..." data-blockingmode="auto" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

I tried to adapt the `template.ftl` in my Keycloak Theme, but this gave me the error
`Refused to frame 'https://the-service-provider/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".`

Can I change the Content-Security-Policy in Keycloak? Or is there a better way to add the JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found out how to change the Content-Security-Policy in Keycloak.

**Realm Settings -> Security Defenses -> Content-Security-Policy**

Here I changed the value to `frame-src 'self' https://the-service-provider; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';`